# Creating a General Graph in Latex

Tags: graphs

I want to create a diagram which resembles the following in Latex.  It a graph to explain piecewise linearization.  I am new to Latex and I am not sure how to start or whether there is another way I can create this image.

[image: Piecewise Linearization]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Maybe http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/linear-regression/ could be a starting point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[latex-latex] (0,6) node[left]{$y$} -- (0,0) coordinate(O) -- (8,0) node[below]{$x$};
  \draw[name path=curve] plot[variable=\x,domain=1:6] ({\x},{exp((\x-1)/6+(\x-1)^2/33)});
  \foreach \X [count=\Y]in {1,2.5,4,5.5}
  {\path[name path=vert-\Y] (\X,0) -- (\X,6);
   \draw[dashed, name intersections={of=curve and vert-\Y}]
   (O -| intersection-1) coordinate(b-\Y) -- (intersection-1) 
   coordinate(int-\Y) -- 
   (O |- intersection-1) coordinate(l-\Y);
   \ifnum\Y>1
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{\Y-1}
    \draw[-latex] ([yshift=0.5cm]b-\Z) --([yshift=0.5cm]b-\Y) node[midway,below]
    {$P_{i\Z}$};
    \draw[-latex] ([xshift=-0.15cm]l-\Z) --([xshift=-0.15cm]l-\Y) 
    node[midway,left]   {$\Delta Z_{i\Z}$};
    \draw[blue] (int-\Z) -- (int-\Y);
   \fi
  }
  \draw[-latex] ([xshift=-0.15cm]O) --([xshift=-0.15cm]l-1) 
    node[midway,left]   {$\Delta Z_{i\mathrm{unreadable}}$};
  \node[below=1mm of b-1] {$P_{i,\mathrm{min}}$};
  \node[below=1mm of b-4] {$P_{i,\mathrm{max}}$};
  \path let \p1=($(int-2)-(int-1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
  node[dashed,draw,ellipse,fit=(int-1) (int-2),rotate fit=\n1](ellipse){};
  \draw ($(int-1)+(0,2)$) coordinate (t1) -- ($(int-2)+(0,2)$) coordinate(t2);
  \draw[dashed] (t1) -- (t1 -| t2) node[midway,below] (P21) {$P_{21}$} 
  -- node[midway,right]{unreadable} (t2);
  \draw[-latex] (ellipse) -- (P21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Is there some tutorial or guide which can show me how to do this on my own?

Comment: @MicahMungal The pgfmanual has a decent tutorial, and there is [VisualTikZ](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf), which I can recommend. But personally I learn most from doing a google search (rather than a search using the search window provided by this site) but put `site:tex.stackexchange.com` in as well as some keywords. A picture search then allows you to judge very quickly if a given post may provide a suitable starting point.

Comment: Also I assume its impossible to get the dotted eclipse with the triangle from the image I posted earlier.  What if I wanted the triangle alone as separate image.  How can I do that?

Comment: @MicahMungal All these things are straightforward, I made a quick update. The greatest challenge is to decipher the symbols of your screenshot and punching them in. Notice that people here typically don't like questions of this type, where one has to punch in the texts. Think of this answer as a welcome present, and please consider adding an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to future questions.